# NgRx Effects crashing Angular app with infinite loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am quite new to NGRx, I am trying to use Effects on my little project as date uses external data I decided to put it in the effects, so app now is crashed with infinite loop after running "npm start", it is just stops working. Here is the link to repo [Github Repo](https://github.com/nurdared/https-github.com-nurdared-ngrx-tutorial-gromax)

### count.effects.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, Effect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import {
  countActionsType,
  CountUpdatedAtAction,
} from './reducers/count/count.actions';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AppEffects {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions) {}

  @Effect()
  updatedAt$() {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(
        countActionsType.increase,
        countActionsType.decrease,
        countActionsType.clear,
        countActionsType.updatedAt
      ),
      map(() => {
        return new CountUpdatedAtAction({
          updatedAt: Date.now(),
        });
      })
    );
  }
}
```

### count.reducer.ts

```
import { CountActions, countActionsType } from './count.actions';

export const COUNT_NODE = 'count';

export interface ICountState {
  count: number;
  updatedAt: number;
}

const initialState: ICountState = {
  count: 0,
  updatedAt: Date.now(),
};

export const countReducer = (state = initialState, actions: CountActions) => {
  switch (actions.type) {
    case countActionsType.increase:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: state.count + 1,
      };
    case countActionsType.decrease:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: state.count - 1,
      };
    case countActionsType.clear:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: 0,
      };
    case countActionsType.updatedAt:
      return {
        ...state,
        updatedAt: actions.payload.updatedAt,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

### count.actions.ts

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export enum countActionsType {
  increase = '[COUNT] increase',
  decrease = '[COUNT] decrease',
  clear = '[COUNT] clear',
  updatedAt = '[COUNT] updated at',
}

export class CountIncreaseAction implements Action {
  readonly type = countActionsType.increase;
}

export class CountDecreaseAction implements Action {
  readonly type = countActionsType.decrease;
}

export class CountClearAction implements Action {
  readonly type = countActionsType.clear;
}

export class CountUpdatedAtAction implements Action {
  readonly type = countActionsType.updatedAt;

  constructor(
    public payload: {
      updatedAt: number;
    }
  ) {}
}

export type CountActions =
  | CountIncreaseAction
  | CountDecreaseAction
  | CountClearAction
  | CountUpdatedAtAction;
```

### count.components.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ICountState } from './reducers/count/count.reducer';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { selectCount, selectUpdatedAt } from './reducers/count/count.selectors';
import {
  CountIncreaseAction,
  CountDecreaseAction,
  CountClearAction,
} from './reducers/count/count.actions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  public count$: Observable<number> = this.store$.pipe(select(selectCount));
  public isButtonDisabled$: Observable<boolean> = this.count$.pipe(
    map((count) => count <= 0)
  );
  public updatedAt$: Observable<number> = this.store$.pipe(
    select(selectUpdatedAt)
  );

  constructor(private store$: Store<ICountState>) {}

  increase() {
    this.store$.dispatch(new CountIncreaseAction());
  }

  decrease() {
    this.store$.dispatch(new CountDecreaseAction());
  }

  clear() {
    this.store$.dispatch(new CountClearAction());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite simple, your effect is triggered when you dispatch some actions, including `countActionsType.updatedAt`.
Inside your effect, you dispatch an Action called `CountUpdatedAtAction`, that has type `countActionsType.updatedAt`.

That's your infinite loop :)

Every time you update, the effect will try to update again, and again, and again :P

To make this work, just remove `countActionsType.updatedAt` in:

```
ofType(
        countActionsType.increase,
        countActionsType.decrease,
        countActionsType.clear,
        countActionsType.updatedAt // <--- remove this
      ),
```

Comment: Sir, I just want to say thank you for you, you made my day, I spent 1.5 day to realize what was wrong, so after creating effect all my actions goes through effect?

Comment: Every time an action inside your `ofType(...)` is dispatched, the effect is also triggered, yes.